# Deleting nodes straight from database

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, nodes

I have a content type in that consists of over 250000 nodes that I want to delete. Deleting in through View Bulk Operations takes way to much time(2+ days) and runs into errors. Is there a faster way to do this straight through the database. So for example can I just empty all the tables in the database that include the fields in that content type. I feel that would delete them 100 times faster but will it cause problems with my website doing it straight of the database?

Answer (score 0):

Activate the query logging feature of the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module. Delete a node. See what queries where executed for the node to be deleted. This should give you a pretty good picture of what needs to be done to delete a node, including queries executed by hooks.

You might also want to have a look at [`node_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7) to see what other actions are executed during node deletion (for example the search index is rebuilt).

To get a picture of what relevant hook implementations exist, you can hack [`module_invoke_all()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7) to log calls to `hook_node_delete` and `hook_entity_delete` and examine if they do additional tasks other than executing database queries.

With this information, you can write a PHP script or [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) command that deletes multiple nodes more efficiently than calling [`node_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7) multiple times. Especially bootstrapping Drupal does not need to be done (or at least not that often).

---

On the other hand, a Drush command that just calls [`node_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7) on the first 50 nodes in question until all relevant nodes are gone is quicker to implement. It might be worth accepting the added processing time to save on development time.